# Show that there exists $Y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $P$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A+XY^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix and $X$ a vector of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $(X,AX,\ldots,A^{n-1}X)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $P$ be a monic polynomial. Show that there exists $Y$ such that $P$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A + X\times Y^{t}$.

I did the case $n=1$, but I’m stuck further... Do you have some advices?

Answer (score 0):

Since the effort shown in the original question is minimal, I will give rather some hints than a complete answer.

- Write out the matrix of $A$ under the basis $(X, AX, \dotsc, A^{n - 1}X)$. Also write out the coordinates of $X$ under this basis.
- Look at the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). How can you produce $P$ as a characteristic polynomial?
- Finally, how to undo the change of basis?